# login/impersonate as local/domain user from app they launched as admin

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wmi

I'm trying to connect to a remote windows server computer on the domain using WMI. It connects fine when launched as the logged in domain user, but when launched as local admin, it fails. Is there a way to tell the app when launched as admin to use the lower domain account to connect?(without prompting for user/password too.)

I've tried:

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate();
```

but it doesn't seem to work even though GetCurrent shows the domain user as the current user.

Comment: is the user logged in as local admin and launching the app? or is the user logged in as domain user but launches the app as local admin?

Comment: Logged in as domain user with app launched as admin.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't be possible without asking for credentials. Good luck!

Comment: In Win32 code, you can get the access token from another process using OpenProcessToken, duplicate it with DuplicateToken, and then use ImpersonateLoggedOnUser.  I'm not sure how this translates to .NET.  Finding the right process might also be a bit tricky.  Another option would be WTSQueryUserToken, but you'd have to install and launch a system service to call it on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with impersonating other domain accounts using [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User) from Uwe Keim.

Comment: This method requires asking for the password, which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`WindowsImpersonationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx) - it has worked reliably for me for switching thread user contexts. It talks directly with **Windows API**.

Comment: Looks like this object is the result of an impersonation attempt, but I'm having trouble getting the app to impersonate with the current logged in domain user.(using the only way I know how to impersonate without password with WindowsIdentity.getCurrent) Maybe you can give more info on how you using it matches up with my problem.

Comment: You could create a **service domain account** that you have credentials for and use it instead of trying to fallback to interactive user. You cannot impersonate unless you have the credentials (*domain/login/pass*).